# Windows 2008 ftp user isolation + public folder

Tags: windows, ftp

I've set up a windows 2008 ftp-server.
Every user can see his homedirectory and write in it.
I would like to make a public folder that everyone can see in their root.
Is this possible? I found the option on filezilla, but not on the build-in windows ftp sever :(

Comment: What Windows OS? and what version of IIS are you using?

Comment: I'm using windows 2008 server and IIS 7

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Windows Server 2012 (an Azure VM), with IIS version 8.5.  I'm fairly certain (given the iis.net link) that this is the same answer for IIS 7.5.

I worked off of http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-the-ftp-service/configuring-ftp-user-isolation-in-iis-7.

I needed to make a folder that "anonymous" users would see read-only, but also give a specific FTP user read/write to the same folder (UserA).  I also had another FTP user that was used for updating the website on the server (C:\inetpub\wwwroot, UserB).

Create UserA and UserB as local users with passwords but no home folders.

In the filesystem, you create C:\inetpub\ftproot\LocalUser, LocalUser\UserA, LocalUser\Public.  I gave modify permission to the UserA and Public folders to UserA.  I gave modify permission to my wwwroot folder to UserB.

In IIS->FTP Authentication, enable both "Anonymous" and "Basic".
In IIS->FTP Authorization Rules, Allow Anonymous users "Read" and Allow UserA and UserB "Read,Write".
In IIS->FTP User Isolation, Isolate Users "User name directory (disable global virtual directories)".

In IIS, under the FTP Site, in the "LocalUser" folder, add a Virtual Directory called "UserB" and have it point to C:\inetpub\wwwroot.  Now my UserB and connect and update website files.

In IIS, user the FTP Site, in the "LocalUser\UserA", create a Virtual Directory call "Anonymous" and have it point to C:\inetpub\ftproot\LocalUser\Public.

Done.  Anonymous FTP logins will be isolated to the Public Folder, UserA will be in their folder, but be able to navigate to the Public folder via the "Anonymous" folder and UserB will be isolated to the wwwroot folder.